# Angular2 and UI library

Tags: angular

In Angular1, we have lots of 3rd ui directives library to build application with, like angular-ui. In Angular2, how to do with these basic ui components, like progress bar, date picker, etc. Shall we just use jquery-ui, or polymer web components?

Cheers,
Ron

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap for example

Comment: Don use jquery libraries directly.. I assume that you would want to invoke those functionalities using jquery techniques. Please don do that. There are plenty of angular libs.. for eg.,. datetime picker, you could use eonasdan datetime picker..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout PrimeNG. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/ It is an open source UI suite for Angular2.

Comment: The most advanced angular ui suite I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Prettyfox UI library http://ng.prettyfox.org

This library use bootstrap 4 styles and not need jquery